# Watching for updates nested within multiple objects passed into angular component

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, d3.js

I have the following Angular controller:

```
{ id: 1, shape: "rect", label: "Start", class: "in-progress",
        subGraph: {
                expand: true,
                nodes: [
                    {id: 10, shape: "rect", label: "Sub Process", class: "in-progress",
                        subGraph: {
                            expand: true,
                            nodes: [
                                {id: 15, label: "Beginning", shape: "rect", class: "default"},
                                {id: 16, label: "Middle", shape: "rect", class: "error"},
                                {id: 17, label: "End", shape: "rect", class: "in-progress"}
                                ],
                             edges: []
                        }},
                           {id: 11, shape: "ellipse", label: "Review", class: "error"},
                           {id: 12, shape: "ellipse", label: "Finalize", class: "default"}
                        ],
                edges: [
                    {from: 10, to: 11, type: "circle", label: "", dashed: false},
                    {from: 11, to: 12, type: "diamond", label: "", dashed: false}
                    ]
            }
    }
```

Here is what the function making the updates in my controller outside the custom component:

```
 // node being updated is passed into the function below
 function onNodeUpdated (node) {
        for (var y = 0; y < this.nodes.length; y++) {
            if (this.nodes[y].id === node.id) {
                    this.nodes.splice(y, 1, angular.copy(this.nodes[y]));
                    break;
            } else if (this.nodes[y].subGraph) {
                for (var x = 0; x < this.nodes[y].subGraph.nodes.length; x++) {
                    if (this.nodes[y].subGraph.nodes[x].id === node.id) {
                        this.nodes[y].subGraph.nodes.splice(x, 1, angular.copy(this.nodes[y].subGraph.nodes[x]));
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

I am passing nodes into my custom angular component as follows in my HTML:

```
 <example nodes="ctrl.nodes" edges="ctrl.edges"></example>
```

Then inside my component I am watching for updates to those nodes as follows inside my link function:

```
  scope.$watchCollection("ctrl.nodes", function() {
                renderGraph();
    });
```

The above watches for changes in the nodes - i.e. different shapes of the nodes, classes added, or node labels changed. When detected the graph re-renders showing the changes to the nodes. This works for the top level nodes - i.e Node with the id #1 below, but not for nested nodes inside the subGraph.

My question is how can I go about listening for changes/updates to the nested edges and nodes - everything within my node with the id of 1. I haven't see an example that has worked yet. All the updates are happening outside of the "example" component. The only thing that is happening inside the component is the watch is being triggered with the new array of nodes and/or edges being passed in.

I've tried:

```
scope.$watch("ctrl.nodes", function() {
             renderGraph();
}, true);

 scope.$watchCollection("ctrl.nodes.subGraph.nodes", function() {
              renderGraph();
});
```

Both tries never call the $watch inside the component, need it to re-render for both node and edge updates. Important note is that I don't know how many subGraphs the user of the component will have, so it needs to be dynamic to account for "n" number of subGraph levels. Is this possible? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$scope.$watch(
function(){ return ctrl.nodes },
function(newVal, oldVal){
             renderGraph();
}, true);
```

or

```
$scope.$watch(
    function(){ return ctrl.nodes.subGraph.nodes },
    function(newVal, oldVal){
                 renderGraph();
    }, true);
```

Also if this code is in the sample directive you can bind to the data on scope in the directive.

You can pretty much put a watcher on anything using this syntax. ie. Services etc...

Comment: The only change I made was to change the second option there to scope.$watchCollection so it didn't update until the user hit the "update" button. I didn't include that in my post though. The watches above fired right away without hitting "update". Thanks

Comment: I'll add it as a seperate question but if anybody knows how to add the watch recursively for "n" levels the subGraph is nested and I also need it to account for each node: ctrl.nodes[i].subGraph.nodes - where "i" is the current node. Currently I am only getting the first parent node.